# TPM authorization Digest calculation

Tags: trusted-platform-module

I am going through Steven Kinney's book; "Trusted Platform Module Basics", and pp 90 - 92 discuss how to calculate the authorization digest. He talks about 1H1, 2H1, 3H1, and 4H1 fields which I do not even see in the corresponding diagram. Can anyone explain this process, or point me to a document which does? If you are going to point me to the specs, please advise with document and section if possible.

I had to read the chapter again, and now I think I can explain my question better. My question is about how the authorization block is calculated; specifically which nonceEven is used for it. The book verbiage on page 90 states that the last nonceEven is used, and that leads me to believe that the nonceEven shown in Fig9.6 is not in the input message. Page 91 even says this explicitly; that "...realize that the last nonceEven is not part of the input message that will be sent to the TPM; this value was previously recorded after the also successful authorized TPM command, in this case, TPM_OIAP." 
So this leads me to wonder why Figure 9.6 has a nonceEven in it. Is it meant to imply that this is the value, which was created by the TPM previously and will be used to calculate the authorization block? I just think it is a little confusing given the description of the figure, which states "TPM_Sign input message block". That nonceEven should be labeled as last nonceEven. It can not be the new nonce either as this is a diagram of a message input, and the new nonceEven would be generated by the TPM.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Figure 9.6 on page 91 explains it all.

Answer (score 2):

The fields are shades of grey encoded:

[image: Figure 9.6 TPM_Sign input message block]

The legend right above the Figure description.